# how to redirect to a url in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am implementing live search and when the user selects any of the options then accordingly the page gets redirected depending on the option selected.

I have jquery for implementing live search .

In the select option :-->>
I want to redirect my page to Index Function in the HomeControllers file using javascript.
The Index function has a few parametres inside it ...

I am not able to redirect ... the url to which i want to send .. gets appended to the current url.

I am doing window.location = "Home/Index/"+ ui.item.value;

kindly suggest what to do ???
waiting for a reply soon.

Comment: maybe if you provide more codes, it will be much easier to answer your question.

Comment: I have to redirect to The url  
"http://localhost.zs.local/Tutorial/Web/Home/Index/1A/1/1"

from "http://localhost.zs.local/Tutorial/Web/Home/Index/3A"

I am doing 
window.location = "Tutorial/Web/Home/Index/?id=" + ui.item.value;

ui.item.value = 3A

Comment: This is likely becuase your routing parameters dont have the property values of the index method defined so don't match the url your redirecting too. please show us your routes and index method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a relative URI. You need to use an absolute URI. So instead of

```
window.location = "Home/Index/"+ ui.item.value;
```

Do

```
window.location = "/Home/Index/"+ ui.item.value;
```

Note the extra `/`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in this way

```
window.location = '<%=Url.Action("Index", "Home")%>?/' + ui.item.value;
```